# Add eth2, eth3 etc. instead of eth1:0, eth1:1 etc

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet

I'm trying to create virtuel ethernet networks on my Debian machine.
I've got 4 static IPs assigned to the machine, and would like them to be virtuel present at eth2, eth3 etc. instead of eth1:0, eth1:1 etc.

Is that possible?

My software needs to believe that there are multiple physical networks attached to the machine.

I've looked at VDE2 by Googling around, but that does not seem to solve the problem or am I mistaken?

Comment: We need to know what version of Debian this is, or if you have a non-default init system installed. Systemd and sysvinit use very different methods for naming interfaces.

Additionally, are you having a problem with your application rejecting sub-interfaces as discrete interfaces, or is this a more cosmetic problem for you? Some additional information on that would be helpful. Specifically, *why* is this a problem?

Comment: I'm running Debian 8 minimal installation on IBM SoftLayer. I want to try PacketFence, an open source NAC. It needs 3-4 physical separated networks and doesn't see the sub-interfaces as separated networks.

Comment: Question: are your sub-interfaces on separate layer-2 domains via VLANs? That might explain why it's rejecting them if not.

Answer (score 1):

`eth0`, `eth1` represent discrete network interfaces. If your machine doesn't have more than one network interface you're only going to have one `eth0` (or `enp1s0`, etc.) interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to use subinterfaces. The below may help

```
$sudo ifconfig eth0:0 ip.addr netmask smn...
```

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing with eth1:0, eth1:1 etc.?

Comment: Maybe miss-read your post, you are wanting to rename the subinterfaces to their respective physical name?

You can change interfaces names using the below command, not sure about sub-interfaces but worth a try.

ifconfig ‌<int> down && ip link set <int> name eth0 && ifconfig eth0 up